# SQLAlchemy Oracle INSERT RETURNING INTO error

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, sql-insert

An insert statement taken verbatim from [SQLAlchemy Core manual](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/dml.html) fails when used with Oracle 11:

```
class OrmT(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    cc = Column(String(6), primary_key=True)
    sector = Column(String(60))

t = OrmT.__table__
t.create(engine)
sel = select([t.c.cc, t.c.sector])
ins = t.insert().from_select(['cc', 'sector'], sel)
engine.execute(ins)
engine.commit()
```

The error message is as follows:

> DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
>   ended

```
'INSERT INTO table1 (cc, sector) SELECT table1.cc,
 table1.sector \nFROM table1 RETURNING table1.cc INTO :ret_0' {'ret_0':
 <cx_Oracle.STRING with value None>}
```

How can I tune SQLAlchemy to fix it? Thank you!

**Update:**

```
ins = t.insert(inline=True).from_select(['cc', 'sector'], sel)
```

makes the problem go away by disabling primary key capture. This is less than perfect solution, particularly when primary keys are needed.

Comment: are you trying to insert a row from a table that you read from that same table?

Comment: @Florian H This is a simple example that is supposed to compile, but does not. Using different tables yields the same error.